# How to disable Akka error messages when client actor disconnect from remote actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I tried to disable following what console message said to me to do: I set akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off and log-dead-letters = off. I even set log-remote-lifecycle-events = off. But seems doesn't work:

[image]

My application.conf of server actor:

[image]

To make the disconnection test I just press "CRTL+C" on client side.

What I need to do to make this work? Am I missing something!

Answer (score 0):

without your code i'm assuming you do not nicely stop your actor system

a couple of options (where system is your actor system):

1) you could use registerOnTermination on your actor system

```
system.registerOnTermination(System.exit(0))
```

2) you could add a shutdownhook which will get called when the JVM exits (f.i by pressing ctrl-c)

from memory so it might be slightly incorrect:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {    
    system.shutdown
  }
}
```